# Explain this function syntax

Tags: php, function

```
function StringCount($searchstring, $findstring)
        {
            return (strpos($searchstring, $findstring) === false ? 0 :  count(split($findstring, $searchstring)) - 1);
        }
```

it returns number of ocourances of substring in string, but why not just use count?

What means `=== false ? 0 :` 
i mean how this called its not if or case is there way to call this type of writing?

Answer (score 1):

This is a type of ternary operator (meaning it takes 3 operands), and is a short form of the if then else clause.

`a ? b : c` can be expanded as:

```
if(a)
{
   b
}
else
{
   c
}
```

So in essence it is something like this:

```
$strPos;
if (($searchstring, $findstring) === false) 
{
   $strPos=0 
}
else
{
   $strPos=count(split($findstring, $searchstring))
}
```

return strpos($strPos-1);

Comment: this explaination is more complete if wrapped in a function, since the whole thing either returns b or c   also called a trinary hook.

Comment: 1.  "Ternary".  In fact, you'll very often hear this called *the* ternary operator, as there are few/no other common ones in C'ish languages.

Comment: `x ? y:z`and `if(x) { y } else { y }` are not exactly the same thing. Yes, it's easier to grasp for beginners when explained this way but no, it's not the same ;-)

Comment: 2.  `b` and `c` are *expressions*, not statements, and the whole result is almost always assigned to something.  (If it's not assigned, many would argue the operator is being abused and should be rewritten as an `if`/`else` statement.)  More correct would be to say that `x = (a ? b : c)` is equivalent to `if (a) x = b; else x = c;`.

Comment: `$previous_comment =~ s:assigned:assigned/returned/passed:g;`

Answer (score 1):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php - about `===`
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary - about `(expr1) ? (expr2) : (expr3)`

But, i think it is better to use `substr_count()` ( http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php ) in this function

Answer (score 0):

Because strpos returns Boolean FALSE, but may also return a non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE, such as 0 or "".

A good example is that StringCount("stackoverflow","stack") will return 0 if

```
function StringCount($searchstring, $findstring)
{
  return (strpos($searchstring, $findstring) == false ? 0 : count(split($findstring, $searchstring)) - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a [ternary condition](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

If `strpos($searchstring, $findstring)` is false, then `0`, else `count(split($findstring, $searchstring)) - 1`

So if `$findstring` is NOT found in `$searchstring`, return `0`

The reason you need 3 `=` for that false statement is [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) returns an integer of where the needle was found in the haystack.  Buy using `===` you get the boolean.